# How to Use/ Display a Asp.net DataList in MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this list below, which I am generating on the fly using Razor view:

```
<table id="contractCoverablesGrid">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var coverableItem in Model.ContractCoverablesList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Hidden("coverID",coverableItem.CoverID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Label(coverableItem.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='checkbox' class='chkboxActive' checked='checked' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can imagine the outcome of this is a vertical list, which keeps extending downwards.

I would like to have this list 'wrapped' into three adjacent columns instead of one single long column; just as you would do this in ASP.net Datalist server control (in Webforms).

My initial thoughts were to limit the width & height of the table to set values and then keep floating the td(s) left. But how do I float a td. I cannot turn this into div.

Any thoughts?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I resolved it:

```
<table id="contractCoverablesGrid" width="600" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var coverableItem in Model.ContractCoverablesList)
            {
                <td>
                    <div id="dataListItem">
                        @Html.Hidden("coverableID", coverableItem.CoverID)
                        @Html.Label(coverableItem.Name)
                        <input type='checkbox' name="coverableItemCheckBox" id="coverableItemCheckBox" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<style>
    #dataListItem {
        float: left;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try a for instead of foreach. You would loop through the list divided by 3 and start a new td each time.

Comment: thanks, I have solved it little differently as you can see above.